# Tor time-size attack

Tags: security, deanonymization, time

What makes it impossible for spying agencies to track whom the user is communicating to by guessing to which packet coming in corresponds a packet going out, based on the very small difference in time and the size of the packet? Is noise caused by the huge amount of transactions the only element that prevents it? If so, wouldn't the client picking a path composed of only low-traffic nodes compromise it?

Comment: I believe you have overstated your case. However, it is difficult but not impossible to track whom the user is based on the method you described. There are much easier ways to identify the users than the method you described and cost benefit analysis clearly indicates the easier methods will be chosen over more difficult methods when appropriate.

Comment: @ARandomGuest Are you assuming that the spying agency can see all packets entering and leaving the Tor network? Tor doesn't claim to protect against that.